# How to validate a condition when a status changes in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vuejs component :

```
Vue.component('update-team-profile-details', {
  props: ['user', 'team'],

  data() {
    return {
      form: new SparkForm({
        name: '',
      })
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.form.name = this.team.name;
  },

  methods: {
    update() {
      Spark.put(…);
    },

    validateSuccess() {
      console.log('no-in-condition')
      if (this.form.successful) {
        console.log('in-condition');
      } 
    },


  },

  computed: {
   /***/
  }
});
```

And I have a form with un event on submit :

```
@click.prevent="update(); validateSuccess();
```

[image]

I would like to post a message thanks to my function `validateSuccess()` but I can never get into my condition. It's always false.

What should I do to make it good?

Thank you

Comment: It's false at first. When I click on the send button, it becomes "true" if it is sent without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your @click directive that is calling the method update()... You should consider moving the validateSuccess as a callback so it will fire after the success or failure of the update method call.

```
@click.prevent="update()"

methods: {
 update() {
   Spark.put(…).then(r=>{
    // is successful 
    this.validateSuccess()
   }).catch(e=>{
    // is failure
    this.validateSuccess()
   });
 },

 validateSuccess() {
   console.log('no-in-condition')
   if (this.form.successful) {
     console.log('in-condition');
   } 
 },
},
```

This is assuming the Spark.put has a promise that it returns

Comment: I tried your solution and it works perfectly. I did not think about that. I'll hold for next time! Thank you !